# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError in IBM RTC Plain Java Client Libraries using Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, rtc

There is an issue which is quite complicated for me that I am using IBM RTC Plain Java Libraries (jar files) in Android App using Android Studio
But on this line:

`ITeamRepository repository = TeamPlatform.getTeamRepositoryService().getTeamRepository(REPOSITORY_ADDRESS);`

I got an Exception `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`

Other than that If I run in Java Application then there is no Exception and everything worked smoothly

Whats the cause, I spent so much time in it
Please guide me
Thanku

Comment: Could you please provide the full stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came to the point that
Some Java APIs are not supported on Android therefore it caused this exception to rise while Initialization at Startup. You need to use RTC Rest APIs or OSLC APIs to extract data instead of these Plain Java Client Libraries.

OR

You can create your own Java Restful Web Service as well which can consume Plain Java Client Libraries and then provide the desired result to Mobile app.